# script is not working properly on Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Link :: http://amatrans.com.previewyoursites.com/

below script are written for slider and its working fine in firefox
but not in

Chrome(mouseover and mouseleave it give white flash)
and

IE(taking too much first time load for hover)

can any one help me in that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(".slides li").each(function(){
            var oldurl =  jQuery(this).css('background-image');
            var imageUrl =  jQuery(this).find('.bw_img').html();
            jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
            jQuery(this).find('.bw_img').html(oldurl);
        }).mouseenter(function(){
            var oldurl =  jQuery(this).css('background-image');
            var imageUrl =  jQuery(this).find('.bw_img').html();
            jQuery(this).css('background-image', imageUrl);
            jQuery(this).find('.bw_img').html(oldurl);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            var oldurl =  jQuery(this).css('background-image');
            var imageUrl =  jQuery(this).find('.bw_img').html();
            jQuery(this).css('background-image', imageUrl);
            jQuery(this).find('.bw_img').html(oldurl);
        });
</script>
```

( Actually i want black image normal and on mouseover colored image of that )

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?
what errors appear in the console?

Comment: actually error is not appear its take time to load

Answer (score 1):

You can preload the images in a hidden container so you don't get flickers when changing the background.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = $('<div id="preloader" />').css('display', 'none').appendTo($(document.body));
    $('<img />').src(imageUrl).appendTo(container);
});
```

Comment: Preloading will not help anything since the images are already loaded.  His jQuery code is simply rearranging existing HTML, not loading anything new.

Answer (score 1):

The flash appears to take place when the B&W image is hidden and the color image is shown.  Since you're using large CSS background images, this will be hard to avoid.

I would suggest retooling your code to use inline images which are absolutely positioned. Then you can simply show the color image on top of the B&W image without removing the B&W image at all.

Comment: thanks
but i used widgetkit for that
and it image used as Background-image
that's why...

Comment: Well, then, you have a fundamental problem. You can try increasing the compression of your images to make the filesizes smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Konstantin re. preloading images - it might be one bottleneck.
Second thing that is that you are creating a lot of closures by iterating all your `<li>` elements and attaching events to them. You're better off using jQuery `on` method, e.g.:

```
jQuery(".slides li").on("mouseenter", function() {
  // your mouseenter code
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  // other code
});
```

This will be more memory-efficient.

**EDIT:** You can rely on CSS for this specific use case:

```
.slides li:hover { filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: thanks using first one Chrome problem is fixed still not fixed in IE

Comment: Like I mentioned on the other answer, preloading is not going to make any bit of difference.  If you look at the HTML code, you'll see that all required images are already loaded.  Please explain.

Comment: You can do all of it in CSS. Outer li has b/w image, inner div has color image. Outer li has `position:relative`, inner div has `position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%`, then you add `.slides li:hover > div { display:none }`